# edittext always gets back focus onFocusChange

Tags: android

So my code does service call when EditText1 loses focus when i click on another edittext. but it focus to the same EditText1 everytime after service call. How can i fix it. Here is my code

```
EditText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus) {
                    if (EditText1.getText().length() >= 5) {

                        searchTask = new SearchTask();
                        searchTask.execute(EditText1.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you have any listener on the second edittext?

Comment: no i dont have any listener

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `editText1.requestFocus();` after `searchTask.execute(...);`

Answer (score 0):

M not sure but try     editText2.requestFocus() after searchTask.execute(EditText1.getText().toString());